Values of unipotent characters on non-unipotent elements of $GL_n(q)$
Let $GL_n(q)$ denote the finite general linear group over a field of size $q=p^t$, and $\chi$ be a unipotent character corresponding to a partition $\lambda$ of $n$. I am currently reading the paper "A Geometric Approach to the Representations of the Full Linear Group Over a Galois Field" by R. Steinberg, and I am assuming that the characters defined there are indeed the '(twisted) unipotent ' characters. Please correct me if I am wrong.
Now, if we choose the partition $(1^n)$, we end up having a special character which is known as Steinberg character and the character values of this are well known; for any non-semisimple element it is zero, and for semisimple element $g$ it is (up to sign) size of the Sylow $p$-subgroup of the centralizer of $g$ in $GL_n(q)$. Furthermore, the sign can be derived from Theorem 9.2 of the paper "Spherical Buildings and the Character of the Steinberg Representation" by C.W. Curtis, G.I. Lehrer, and J. Tits.
I do not understand this fully, but vaguely, for other unipotent characters the values at unipotent elements are given by Green functions for the case of $GL_n(q)$, and in general some cohomological description applies for other finite reductive groups.
Here is my question: what are the character values of unipotent characters (other than the Steinberg character) on non-unipotent elements of $GL_n(q)$, at least on the semisimple elements? A reference will be really helpful. I appreciate any help you can provide.
